# How do I replace an attribute value for attribute with multiple values in Wicket?

Tags: wicket

My class attribute has two CSS class values.  The HTML starts out like this:

```
<input type="button" wicket:id="rowButton" class="jelly-button greenGradient"/>
```

And I want to dynamically change it to this:

```
<input type="button" wicket:id="rowButton" class="jelly-button redGradient"/>
```

Currently I am doing this:

> component.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("class", "jelly-button redGradient"));

What is the best way to do this in Wicket?  There must be a more 'proper' way to do this than what I have done above.

Comment: What exactly is the behavior you expect/how should the method call look like? BTW, you should use `AttributeModifier.replace` as `SimpleAttributeModifier` has been deprecated in Wicket 1.5 and removed in Wicket 6.0.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Instead of using an attribute modifier with fixed text you could use an attribute appender with the text retrieved from a model. To change the class, just change the model's value. For example:

```
Model<String> gradientModel = new Model<String>("greenGradient");
```

...

```
component.add(AttributeModifier.append("class", gradientModel));
```

in the markup just have

```
<input type="button" wicket:id="rowButton" class="jelly-button"/>
```

Then when it is time to change the gradient use

```
gradientModel.setObject("redGradient");
```

or

```
gradientModel.setObject("greenGradient");
```

Answer (score 0):

The example in the javadoc below explains it well
http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/apache/wicket/wicket-core/1.5.2/wicket-core-1.5.2-javadoc.jar!/org/apache/wicket/behavior/AttributeAppender.html